# Video has multiple resolutions in Quicktime but ffmpeg only sees one

Tags: video, ffmpeg, metadata, mp4, screen-recording

[image: Quicktime screenshot]

Quicktime is showing me multiple resolutions for this screen recording, I would assume one is the initial screen resolution and the other one is the cropped resolution from the screen recording. The video displays in quicktime as 810x1080 but when grabbing a frame from the video with ffmpeg it saves it as 1418x1080. I can't figure out where the 810 comes from in the metadata, neither `mediainfo` nor `ffprobe` show anything about it.

VLC will display the video initially with the 1418x1080 resolution and then switch to 810x1080 if I try to resize.

I'm clearly missing something but I can't figure out what it is, maybe an only partially supported metadata tag?

Ultimately I want to grab frames from the video with `ffmpeg` with an automated script so it'd be great to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is the displayed resolution (1418x1080) vs. the actual stored resolution in the video file (810x1080).  Sometimes video needs to be displayed at oddball resolutions, but the video encoding requires proper sized macroblocks.  In these cases, it's common for there to be extra off-screen padding.

Note however that the video resolution can change mid-stream.  Who knows what's actually in this file without seeing it.  The file info dialog doesn't really give you this information.

FFmpeg is probably doing the right thing here.

Comment: Thanks Brad. Do you know if there is a way to extract what dimensions the frame is at a particular timestamp? When I try to extract a frame it stretches it to fit the larger dimensions rather than displaying it as it would be shown

Comment: @quacainia It should do this automatically.  I suspect that your video file is broken.